# Linq complex select

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
public class Draw
{
    public int DrawId { get; set; }         
    public virtual ICollection<Figure> Figures { get; set; }

}
public class Figure { 
    public Type type { get; set; } 
    public double Area { get; set; }     
}

public enum Type { Square = 0, Triangle = 1, Circle = 2}
```

If I have a list of objects Draw, how can make a linq query to select all Draws
with at least two figures with area over 5 of at least two different types.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? StackOverflow isn't just for getting other people to code for you

Comment: What problems are you having with your attempted solutions?

Comment: I just learning about Linq, i'm bloked with more complex querys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = draws.Where(draw => draw.Figures
    .Where(figure => figure.Area > 5)
    .Select(figure => figure.type)
    .Distinct()
    .Count() >= 2);
```